# writing nftables for traffic pre/postrouting to an IDS

Tags: iptables, nftables

Trying to learn nftables since it has been implemented on Openwrt 22.03 with little backwards compatibility for iptables.

I have iptables rules for forwarding traffic from my router to a VM running Suricata:

```
iptables -i eth0 -t mangle -A PREROUTING --s 0/0 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.1.156
iptables  -i eth0.2 -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.1.156
```

What would people recommend as nftables rules for this? I'm trying to learn from the results of converting them, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `iptables-translate` utility. It will translate iptables rules to nftables. For your rules the commands would be:

```
iptables-translate -i eth0 -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 0/0 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.1.156
iptables-translate -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.1.156
```

and the results are:

```
nft add rule ip mangle PREROUTING iifname "eth0" counter dup to 192.168.1.156
nft add rule ip mangle POSTROUTING ip saddr 192.168.0.0/24 counter dup to 192.168.1.156
```

Also take a look here https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Moving_from_iptables_to_nftables

Comment: Yes, does that make sense according to nftables syntax? Are there alternatives for mirroring the traffic to that specific gateway?

Comment: @robreiner of course it makes sense. The best is to check yourself `man nft` for the `dup` parameter, and to try the answer (including the wiki link, and adding the forgotten `-i eth0.2` to the translation).